# java BigInteger manipulation

Tags: java, biginteger

The following code is for debugging:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger("10000000001");
    String sn = n.toString();
    char[] array = sn.toCharArray();
    //intend to change value of some char in array
    //not standard math operation
    BigInteger result = new BigInteger(array.toString());
}
```

It gives me error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[C@86c347"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:316)
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:451)
        at debug.main(debug.java:14)
```

But it was working fine, until this case, I'm not quite sure what went wrong.

Comment: Try to print `array.toString()` since it seems to be an invalid input string for the BigInteger constructor.

Comment: `it was working fine, until this case` could you show some other cases where it worked fine?

Comment: I swear it worked for a while..thank you for all of your efforts, it also puzzled me that somehow it worked for a few inputs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, add more diagnostics... taking out statements which do two things. This:

```
array.toString()
```

won't do what you expect it to, because arrays don't override `toString()`. It'll be returning something like `"[C@89ffb18"`. You can see this by extracting an extra local variable:

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger("10000000001");
String sn = n.toString();
char[] array = sn.toCharArray();
String text = array.toString();
BigInteger result = new BigInteger(text);
```

Then in the debugger you should easily be able to look at the value of `text` before the call to `BigInteger` - which would show the problem quite clearly.

To convert a char array to a string containing those characters, you want:

```
new String(array)
```